image(in FormData as Blob) upload problem in webapp(react+.net)
I am developing a web app using React(TS)+.net+sqlserver.
There is a function to let user post their photos.
The problem is photos cannot be uploaded and always received by backend as null.
Below are my frontend codes:
//I storage image as byte[] at backend, so format transfer needed.
const fileToUint8Array = (file: File): Promise<Uint8Array> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                if (reader.result instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
                    const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
                    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                    resolve(uint8Array);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('Failed to read file as ArrayBuffer.'));
                }
            };
            reader.onerror = (error) => {
                reject(error);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    };

const formData = new FormData();
if (selectedFile) {
 const byteArr = await fileToUint8Array(selectedFile);
 console.log(byteArr); //here I can get byte data Uint8Array(123808) [...]
 formData.append('ImageData', new Blob([byteArr], { type: selectedFile.type }));
};

console.log('FormData before sending:', formData); 
//console output: formData before sending: FormData {}

const response = await agent.addScenery(formData, config);

console.log('Response from backend:', response); 
//console output: {sceneryId: '...', sceneryName: '...', country: '...', city: '...', imageData: null, …}

below are my .net backend codes
[Authorize]
[Route("[action]")]
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddScenery([FromForm] SceneryAddRequest sceneryAddRequest)
{
Console.WriteLine($"Received add request: ImageData={sceneryAddRequest.ImageData?.Length} bytes");
...
//backend console output: Received add request: ImageData= bytes

How should I solve this problem?
I tried to check what backend received from frontend, and found that imagedata is received as null

Please set a brealpoint in your AddScenery method, make sure the http request can invoke it.
I test in my local and below sample works in my side, hope it can inspire you.
SceneryAddRequest.cs
public class SceneryAddRequest
{
    public string SceneryName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "ImageData")]
    public IFormFile ImageData { get; set; }
}

Program.cs(enable cors)
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();

SceneryController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ReactApp1.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SceneryController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AddScenery")]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddScenery([FromForm] SceneryAddRequest sceneryAddRequest)
        {
            if (sceneryAddRequest.ImageData != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Received add request: ImageData={sceneryAddRequest.ImageData.Length} bytes");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received add request: ImageData is null");
            }
            return Ok(new { message = "Upload successful" });
        }
    }

}

UploadComponent.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const UploadComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

    const fileToUint8Array = (file: File): Promise<Uint8Array> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                if (reader.result instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
                    const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
                    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                    resolve(uint8Array);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('Failed to read file as ArrayBuffer.'));
                }
            };
            reader.onerror = (error) => {
                reject(error);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    };

    const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const files = event.target.files;
        if (files && files.length > 0) {
            setSelectedFile(files[0]);
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!selectedFile) return;

        const formData = new FormData();
        const byteArr = await fileToUint8Array(selectedFile);
        formData.append('ImageData', new Blob([byteArr], { type: selectedFile.type }));
        formData.append('SceneryName', '1');
        formData.append('Country', '2');
        formData.append('City', '3');

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:7204/api/scenery/AddScenery', formData, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            });
            console.log('Response from backend:', response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default UploadComponent;

Test Result


